Someone claimed they sent 5,000$ to my cash app is that a scam or not?
Someone on Facebook claimed they sent me 5,000$ and is saying it will be a blessing of my day what should I do he provided evidence of the payment with a picture but the transaction is not showing in my cash app I looked online and it said that it may take 4 to 5 days for the transaction to go through! But he did sen me evidence, but I just don’t know what to believe at this point 

Why have you added dodgy looking links at the top of the question? Of course it's a scam, nobody gives you $5000 out of nowhere. Ignore it and block them.

Thank you for your answer Vicky I appreciate it

this person has not sent you $5000. They have pretended to send you $5000. You might want to think about why they did that and what they expect you to do in the next 4-5 days (which could easily extend with "oh I talked to customer service and there's a problem with your bank but it will all be taken care of in another 4-5 days" and so on)

Why the downvotes? If nothing else this question informs us of a scam we may not have known.

There are an infinitude of scams. This one is effectively identical to some we've discussed in the past; essentially a kited check. I wouldn't down-vote it, but we do sora hope people will make some effort to look at the accumulated wisdom before posting; SE's stated goal is to evolve toward being a FAQ repository rather than just a Q&A site.

Anyone can forge a screenshot, the evidence means nothing.
There are multiple options here:

They did send you something, which will in fact arrive, and they will later ask for (some/all) of it back under various pretenses. This is money laundering, you'd be used as a mule. The source is criminal and you'd be the loose end for the law enforcement to find. The original transfer will, likely, be eventually reversed.

They did send you something, which will in fact arrive, and they'll later ask you to do something or to buy something. This is essentially the same, except in addition to the money laundering you'd be committing actual crimes (buying stolen property, for example). The original transfer will, likely, be eventually reversed.

They didn't send anything, but they will drag it on for a while and then will start asking for various fees that they need to pay for the money to come through. That's a vanilla advanced fee scam.

They didn't send anything, but they will say "oh, I need the money back urgently" and will ask you to send the money back to them and wait for the original transfer to go through (which it never will). That's just plain fraud.


